What is the specific regulation that requires the AFM and weight and balance information to be onboard the aircraft?
14 cfr 91.9 does require that "there is available in the aircraft a current, approved Airplane or Rotorcraft Flight Manual", but only for U.S registered civil aircraft "for which an AFM is required by 14 CFR 21.5" Reading through 21.5, it seems to only apply to a fraction of registered civil aircraft.
I've also tried looking in 14 cfr part 23 and 25, to no avail.
Thank you

Seems answered in: Which regulations require the ARROW documents?

that answer references 91.9, which doesn't seem to apply to most registered civil aircraft

But doesn't part 91 apply to all aircraft as general rules which can be made more stringent under other specific parts?

Read the full 91.9... for some aircraft it requires one thing (AFM), while for others it requires something else.
